# position relative elements after absolute elements

Tags: css

I have a site with absolute positioned elements on it, for example the top Navigation of the site:

```
#topNav
{
  position:     absolute;
  top:          100px;
  left:         50%;
  height:       40px;
  width:        1000px;
  margin-left:  -500px;
}
```

Now I created a sticky footer like on the following site:
http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Now, the problem is that the footer will "overlap" the topNav,
because the topNav is positioned absolute, which means it's "outside of the normal float of elements". The relative position will not "notice" that there is the topNav before.

Before I start creating additional "pusher divs" for each absolute positioned element I would better ask if there are better practices than "pusher divs" or should I even not use position absolute on my elements?

**EDIT:**
JsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dkxUX/15/

When you scale down your browserwindow you'll find #footer overlapping all elements before it.

Comment: Could you supply some HTML code and CSS for the footer, even better a jsfiddle example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just apply a 140px top margin/padding to the body or other container element which would make the topNav's height and offset accounted for.

Better yet, don't set position to absolute in this case - it appears to me that all you're doing is horizontally centering a 1000px wide div.

```
/*top-margin of 100px + center the element*/
#topNav {width:1000px; height:40px; margin:100px auto 0;}
```

Update: I see your jsfiddle now. <del>You could account for all absolutely positioned elements when setting the margin/padding as suggested in the first paragraph</del> You are using absolutely positioned elements when normal document flow could be relied on.

Comment: While this is good for the topNav it can't solve for example the positioning of the "callUs" div 20px from the top & 500px to the right from the middle.

Comment: I updated the JsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dkxUX/15/

Seems like I've missed something out. How would I position the Logo & the Telephone-number relayed on the static document flow?

Comment: I'd set logo as a background image on some generic div#header and stick all "header" content including the phone number in there. Phone number could `float:right;` or be absolutely positioned *within* the #header, but that's just me

Answer (score 2):

a little bit too late to give an answer but it may help someone in the future, I came up with that problem not too long ago so here was my shot at it, using jquery since I couldn't came up with a CSS solution that wasn't removing the DOCTYPE tag (which isn't something you should do, anyways).

So here it is.

```
$("#CONTAINERDIV").prepend("<div id='relativefix' style='position:relative;margin-top:"+($("#YOUR_ABSOLUTE_DIV").offset().top+$("#YOUR_ABSOLUTE_DIV").outerHeight()+30)+"px'></div>");


$(window).resize(function(){
$("#relativefix").css("margin-top",($("#YOUR_ABSOLUTE_DIV").offset().top+$("#YOUR_ABSOLUTE_DIV").outerHeight()+30)+"px");
            });
```

So yeah, that's all there is to it, you just dynamically add another div at the start of the container hard-placed under the absolute div, that will force all subsequent relative divs to me placed after it, it is like a clear fix for someone who ran out of ideas.

Comment: Thank for you leaving an answer, this helped me a lot today.