# Fixing problematic layout / How to get elements height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**this question is related to my before question:**
[position relative elements after absolute elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152274/position-relative-elements-after-absolute-elements)

I updated the JsFiddle provided there to reflect my current html (for which I've no URL right now) more exact. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/dkxUX/22/

I realised that this layout is problematic for me.

In the comments to o.v.'s answer he pointed out that I could create additional wrappers,
like for example a #header div. This is not a bad idea indeed, since this way I would still be able to position my elements absolute within it, however - as long it is positioned anything else than static.

**And here comes my problem:**

I was curious if the height of an absolute positioned element will affect the height of its parent.
Actually, it seems not: http://jsfiddle.net/qFh6s/1/

Beeing frustrated I tried it with jQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/WD6LF/1/

Result: Beeing even more frustrated, running out of ideas.

I just cannot give the elements fixed heights, because their content will vary.

Actually, I'm already annoyed by my html, for example the additional wrappers for the sticky footer make it seeming less semantic to me. Furthermore, I begin to understand that putting everything into divs and giving it an absolute position is NOT the answer to all CSS hurdles.
So I'm open to any useful suggestion, whilst making myself ready to scratch everything and start over.

Comment: It can be fixed with JavaScript, but you should instead redo the layout CSS. Think of it as a learning experience. I can confirm that using `position: absolute` for everything is pretty much the worst technique to create that layout. Even using a `<table>` for layout would be better.

Comment: Is there even an alternative to using a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really look into floats. Floats will help you position elements even if there height is not known. And you will stop swearing...:)

Good designers do not use tables or positioning, they use floats. You can use clear:both on any div if you don't want it to follow any other div. I didn't quite completely read your question but I am pretty much sure its floats you are looking for. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) is a quick tutorial on floats. Go through it and you yourself will be able to solve your problem. I hope your problem gets solved. Happy designing!!